# Which unsupervised clustering algorithm from the sklearn library can I use with custom distance?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a function that takes as input two samples and return their distance and from this function I have defined a metric

```
def TwoPointsDistance(x1, x2):
    cord1 = f.rf.apply(x1)
    cord2 = f.rf.apply(x2)
    return 1 - (cord1==cord2).sum()/f.n_trees

metric = sk.neighbors.DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc',
                                                     func=TwoPointsDistance)
```

Now I would like to cluster my data according to this metric.  I would like to see some examples of algorithms for unsupervised clustering that use this as a distance metric.

EDIT: I am particularly interested in this algorithm:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN

EDIT: I have tried

```
DBSCAN(metric=metric, algorithm='brute').fit(Xor)
```

but I receive an error:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 249, in fit
    clust = dbscan(X, **self.get_params())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py", line 100, in dbscan
    metric=metric, p=p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/unsupervised.py", line 83, in __init__
    leaf_size=leaf_size, metric=metric, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 127, in _init_params
    % (metric, algorithm))
ValueError: Metric '<sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.PyFuncDistance object at 0x7ff5c299f358>' not valid for algorithm 'brute'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to figure out why this error arises... I first thought `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors` (which is what DBSCAN is based upon) would be constrained to those distances listed in `sklearn.neighbors.base.VALID_METRICS["brute"]`. But judging from the source code, any `callable` function should be okay - so it seems your distance isn't callable?

Please try this:

```
DBSCAN(metric=TwoPointsDistance, algorithm='brute').fit(Xor)
```

i.e. without wrapping your distance as `neighbors.DistanceMetric`. It seems a bit inconsistent to me to now allow these to be used here...

Myself, I have used ELKI with great success with a custom distance function, and there is a short tutorial on how to write these available: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions

Comment: Thanks for answering. At the end I have found a workaround. I have computed the distance between samples and saved it in a matrix d of size n_samples x n_samples.  Then I have used as metric precomputed and as input the matrix d.

Answer (score 0):

Today, years later, I still stumbled over this in a different context. The solution is simple: pass the function directly as a metric.

`BSCAN(metric=TwoPointsDistance, algorithm='brute').fit(Xor)`